# How can I programmatically create APNG files?

Tags: imagemagick, apng

Generally I use PHP, and ImageMagick, but as far as I can tell it seems the ImageMagick group refuse to implement the ability to create/understand animated PNG files?

What tooling can I implement to take a dozen JPEG files and create an animated PNG out of them?  I'd prefer to have a PHP api, but I can branch out into another language if required!

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this? https://github.com/eight04/pyAPNG

Comment: Why do you use APNG? It has never been widely supported. WebP has got a lot more traction.

Comment: AFAIK you're wrong, APNG actually has better support than WebP.

https://caniuse.com/#feat=apng
https://caniuse.com/#feat=webp

Crucially WebP is missing MacOS/iOS Safari support, which is HUGE, where in contrast APNG misses IE11/Edge, which is a tiny percentage (and declining) of my users.

Comment: Edge now supports APNG.

Comment: @orionelenzil But sadly not Powerpoint

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[As of ImageMagick 7.0.10-31](https://imagemagick.org/script/changelog.php), Animated PNG [is supported](https://imagemagick.org/script/formats.php#supported).

```
magick -delay 100 -loop 0 frame1.png frame2.png APNG:myanimation.png
```

parameters:
`-delay 100` specifies a duration of 100 centiseconds (aka one second) per frame before moving on to the next frame.
`-loop 0` tells the animation to repeat forever.
`APNG:___.png`  specifies the output should be animated png.

(thanks to @fmw42 for improvements)

note: on MacOS Ventura, this seems to require ffmpeg as well.

Comment: Your syntax is not actually correct. You specify it properly as `magick -delay 100 -loop 0 frame1.png frame2.png APNG:myanimatedpng.png` Note the APNG: preface and that it is actually a sub function of png. Also in Imagemagick 7, use magick, not magick convert.  The changelog lists it as added 7.0.10.31

Comment: thank you for these. updated. in my own work I realized "apng:foo.png" was better, but forgot to come back and edit my answer.

Comment: I did give you an up vote for your answer anyway already as you properly noted that Imagemagick can do that.

Comment: lol, i keep searching "imagemagick animated png" and coming back to this page and upvoting this answer and then wondering why my upvote isn't working.

Comment: You can only upvote once on any given topic. Also you cannot upvote your own answer.

Comment: :) yes, i know. i keep forgetting it's my answer.